# Locate When a Range of Values Begin to Increase

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm performing a temperature profile curve and need to automate the process as much as possible. I need to determine when the part actually begins to heat up over a time period. I currently do this manually by scrolling through the thousands of data points until I see an increase. The part will be at room temp for a time and then slowly start to increase.

The increase should be slight at ~1°C meaning if B327 reads 27.5°C and B328 reads 28.6°C this would be my start point.

Once the temperature increases, the time would be displayed and further calculations will be performed.

I'm using Excel for the data analysis and would prefer to use formulas vs VBA so the document is easier to maintain for future use.

Comment: Should be easy enough to check the different between two consecutive points and see if it is more than 1°. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think it should be easy as well but for some reason I'm left scratching my head. I can get it to work by adding a second column with =IF(ABS(B1-B2)>1,A1,"") then just searching for the first time in the first column. My goal is to have it all in one cell so I won't have to add a separate column. With VBA I could just loop through the column but again I'd like to keep to formulas for simplicity. Maybe I'm making it harder than it should be...

Comment: What is your expected output? and I would not use `ABS` as it will also flag a 1° decrease in temperature

Comment: All I'm after is the start time of the temp increase. Column A is time (seconds) column B is temperature (°C). The data updates every ~0.2s so once the temp starts to increase it will generally keep increasing exponentially afterwards.

Comment: Is a helper column OK? if yes, have one that calculates the difference between each row (`=B3-B2`), then use `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,C:C,1))` to get the time when the increase starts

Comment: Are you saying you expect to see a one degree increase between two consecutive datapoints (which would be only 200msec apart) ?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I can start with a helper column but ideally it would be contained in as few rows as possible. I tried your suggestion but I think it's running into issues with the MATCH portion since the data is not sorted.

Comment: @Tim Williams The temperature will increase at more than one degree between two consecutive data points (anywhere from 2 to 4 degrees). The temperature of the part will be hovering around the same temp until it starts heating up so I really could be looking for even smaller temp changes like 0.1°C.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula like:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,(A2:A11-A1:A10)>0.1,0)     '<< Use Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

this calculates an array of TRUE/FALSE where the difference between consecutive rows is >0.1 (adjust to suit) and uses MATCH to find the position of the first TRUE value

Comment: This works great, thank you. I modified it slightly because at >0.1 I noticed I was getting noise so I changed it to =INDEX(A11:A705,MATCH(1,(N11:N705>0.1)*(N12:N706>0.1),0)) which ensures the temp is consecutively increasing. The INDEX portion pulls the temp increase start time which @cybernetic.nomad suggested.